# Android data binding not updating the view properly

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, android-databinding

I'm trying to show country codes and flags in a login fragment that user chose from a dialog including a list of countries and a textview for search. for countries and search, I use a recyclerview and android pagedlist library. I'm using observablefield in ViewModel for data and databinding in XML .the problem is when you search the countries. if the country code is, for example, two digits, and then you change the country with a country that has a three-digit code, the textview only shows 2 digits of country code. it only occurs when you use search
it's probably because the textview width(which is wrap-content) does not update. I don't know why!!!!

this is the picture for Afghanistan which has a 2 digit code and it works fine
[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d3Nvf.jpg)

but after that, I change the country to Andorra which has a three-digit code(+376) and it only shows the first two digits(+37)
[this is the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuWRt.jpg)

I've tried using live data instead of an observablefield but it didn't help.
I've also tried to change the country code without data-binding but it didn't fix the problem.
the data updates just fine when I watch it in the debugger but it doesn't show all the digits in the textview.
if you don't use search it works just fine.

this is the code for flag and country code xml which is in a cardview

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/countryCode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:text="@{ viewModel.mobileCode }"
    android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    tools:text="+1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/countryFlag"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/country"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
    android:visibility='@{ viewModel.mobileCode == "" ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE }'
    app:error="@{ @drawable/ic_placeholder_flag }"
    app:imageCornerRadius="@{ 8 }"
    app:imageUrl="@{ viewModel.flagUrl }"
    app:placeholder="@{ @drawable/ic_placeholder_flag }"
    tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_placeholder_flag" />
```

this is the code in login fragment which updates the data form the CountiyDialog. showDialog method in CountryDialog takes a lambda

```
binding.countryFlag.setOnClickListener {
    CountryDialogFragment.showDialog(fragmentManager!!, true) { country ->
        viewModel.mobileCode.set(country.phoneCode)
        viewModel.flagUrl.set(country.imageUrl)
    }
}
```

Comment: take a pic of UI with wrong TextView size. What layout do you use? Could you use `android:layout_width="match_parent"` with `android:text_align="end"` ?

Comment: @anatoli I use constraint layout and in the cardview I use linear layout. I've also added the pictures in the question